# ld.exe can't find libraries during cabal-install (Haskell Platform)

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal-install, haskell-platform

I have `Win 10 @ x64` computer. I installed Haskell Platform `(HP) 8.0.1`, but then realized that the package I need have troubles when building with `GHC 8`. So I uninstalled `HP 8` and installed `HP 7.10.3` instead. The `config` file in cabal directory remained from 8-installation, so I removed it manually (as cabal from `7.10.3` couldn't parse it).

Now I have problem cabal-installing any package which implies building executable file. See example of building `cheapskate` below. I had very similar messages when building `yaml`, so I guess there is nothing specific to package itself. Just as I say the problem with any package installing executable.

```
Linking dist\build\cheapskate\cheapskate.exe ...
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSxss-sanitize-0.3.5.7-HScF09TDCPn9q2HNPyr3jY
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSutf8-string-1.0.1.1-L8eKHa7Iv9q7FVKUYW6u4b
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHStagsoup-0.14-LkUWVoqDDljLCcz7bB5oLY
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHScss-text-0.1.2.1-EIrTNZIusX93HMVzZkp9UD
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSuniplate-1.6.12-DgRHum07M0vBMdvTsdo5gV
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSdata-default-0.7.1.1-3MPp9dYgnh90NQDAZx5NXx
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSdata-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1-K6L8Um6XgJK7vZZFbrTNny
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSdata-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1-H5f5Qu8KYxpJlVdwCzbtAY
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSdlist-0.7.1.2-AO7XAasbAeyL0XLKeq1Aui
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSdata-default-instances-containers-0.0.1-Lel7wFldMDA1Zs74nVWKYF
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSdata-default-class-0.1.2.0-4JL8mCHvyuoKtdHwhiuMnt
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSblaze-html-0.8.1.1-89cVIlB12sFJRMi1lQAdfn
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSblaze-markup-0.7.0.3-7gHcQviMQE9GGsKcO1ZT0j
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSblaze-builder-0.4.0.2-4HkRnVv5mkB1jlZDT6uaGq
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cheapskate-0.1.0.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The description seems to correspond to a corrupted package database.

`ghc-pkg check` can help see if this is the case, and `ghc-pkg recache` can potentially help fix things. If this fails, the local package database directory, which is one of the two listed with `ghc-pkg list`, can just be deleted.